Print larger font to the screen with golang in ebiten
I have have a chessboard, and need to display the piece on the board, eg K, Q, P, etc
However i am only able to print the text in one size (small)
How can i write larger text to the screen? eg font size 32

I tried to create a font from the below package, however i can't get it larger in size.
https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/image@v0.15.0/font/basicfont
Ideally need a simple way with Ebitengine v2 to write text of to a position on the screen of any size and color. https://github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/blob/v2.7.2/text/v2/text.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image/color"
    "log"

    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2"
    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/ebitenutil"
    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/text"
    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/vector"
    "golang.org/x/image/font/basicfont"
)

// Game represents the game state
type Game struct {
}

func (g *Game) Update() error {
    return nil
}

func (g *Game) Draw(screen *ebiten.Image) {

    vector.DrawFilledRect(screen, float32(0), float32(0), float32(100), float32(100), color.Black, true)
    vector.DrawFilledRect(screen, float32(100), float32(0), float32(100), float32(100), color.White, true)

    // print text, default
    ebitenutil.DebugPrintAt(screen, fmt.Sprintf("%v", "K"), 50, 50)

    //with color, but font is still small
    exampleImage := ebiten.NewImage(50, 50)
    exampleImage.Fill(color.RGBA{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff})

    op := &ebiten.DrawImageOptions{}
    op.GeoM.Translate(float64(125), float64(25))
    screen.DrawImage(exampleImage, op)

    var myFont = &basicfont.Face{
        Advance: 7,
        Width:   32,
        Height:  32,
        Ascent:  11,
        Descent: 2,
        Mask:    basicfont.Face7x13.Mask,
        Ranges: []basicfont.Range{
            {'\u0020', '\u007f', 0},
            {'\ufffd', '\ufffe', 95},
        },
    }

    text.Draw(screen, fmt.Sprint("Q"), myFont, 150, 50, color.RGBA{0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff})

}

func (g *Game) Layout(outsideWidth, outsideHeight int) (screenWidth, screenHeight int) {
    return 640, 640
}

func main() {
    ebiten.SetWindowSize(640, 640)
    if err := ebiten.RunGame(&Game{}); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}


Can you please include a fully reproducible example? The example code isn't runnable as-is.

Sure, I'll change to a executible version. In the next few days

@coxley updaed, sorry for the delay. I added working code example, and a image of what the output is currently.

Ah, the documentation is not entirely clear on this. The example at https://github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/blob/main/examples/fontfeature/main.go will point you in the right direction.
Basically, you'll want to load a TTF font and then during the draw, you can use:
&text.GoTextFace{
    Source: firaSansFaceSource,
    Size:   20,
}

That makes the fonts sizable.
